# Angular js : How to disable the formly form?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I need to disable the whole **formly form** and not just the fields.

That is, disable the whole form so that the **form is disabled** and not just in readonly mode?

Can anyone please help.

Below is my sample code.I need a property which can **disable the whole form**.

```
$scope.formOptions = {
    formState : {
        readOnly : true
    }
};
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell exactly what you're asking but if you wrap form elements (inputs, buttons, etc) in a `<fieldset>` and set its `disabled` attribute, all child elements will be disabled, eg `<fieldset ng-disabled="disabledFlag">`

Comment: Can you please give an example.

Comment: pleaase add your code

Comment: you may be use ng-show or ng-hide directives

Comment: @Tink I already did

Comment: Not able to find the correct answer yet.

Comment: please add your template means html page

Comment: How can I add a property in the above mentioned code?

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
formlyConfigProvider.setType({
    name : 'input',
    wrapper : [ 'bootstrapLabel',
    'bootstrapHasError' ],
    templateUrl : 'Forminput.html',
    overwriteOk : true
});



<p ng-if="formState.readOnly">{{model[options.key].name}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case to hide formly form you need to use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directives.

And from your controllers you can decide whether hide or show based on scope variable.

**For example** :

In your controller

```
 $scope.isHideForm = true ;
```

In your view (html template)

```
  <formly-form ng-hide="isHideForm">
    <!-- more code -->
  </formly-form>
```

Hope this will help you !